# Verilog module 3-Bit Output

Tags: module, output, warnings, verilog, hardware

My problem seems really simple but somehow I can't get it to work.
I am trying to create a module in verilog which outputs a 3bit signal. I've tried so many different methods so far but none of them seem to work.
I am using Veriwell to compile my code and since I am doing this for university I am oblieged to use it so please don't recommend me different compilers.

Here are some methods I've tried but none of them worked
(I always get a 'Port sizes don't match in port #2' warning)

```
module testmod (in, out);
  input [2:0] in;
  output [2:0] out;

  wire [2:0] out;
  assign out = in;  //trying just to connect in to out
endmodule

module testmod (in, out);
  input [2:0] in;
  output [2:0] out;

  wire [2:0] out;
  assign out = 3'b1;  //trying to assign a random value to out
endmodule

module testmod (in, out);
  input [2:0] in;
  output [2:0] out;
  reg [2:0] test;
  always @(in)
    test = in;        //saving in in a register (which i believe is unnecessary but I've tried it nonetheless)

  wire [2:0] out;
  assign out = test;  //trying just to connect in to out
endmodule
```

I instanciate the module like this:

```
testmod mod (.in(3'b1), .out(out));
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring out as a 3-bit signal in my testbench did the job. Since I've only worked with 1-bit output signals which apparently don't need to be declared at all in the testbench this didn't even come to my mind.